# What lexical relationship lies between the days of the week?

Tags: meaning, semantics, semantic-shift, category, lexicon

I'm confused, What is the lexical relationship between "Monday" and "Tuesday"?

I mean is the relationship hyponymy, prototypes, polysemy, homophones, metonymy etc?

Comment: Tuesday comes after Monday, so the lexical relation is temporal. They're one of a set of special proper names, and they don't have normal morphology or syntax, if that's what you mean. Otherwise, I can't see what you're asking about.

Comment: I don't think the "lexical relation is temporal" between Monday and Tuesday.  Certainly |Monday| (the day) comes before |Tuesday| (the day.)  However, the signifier "Monday" is arbitrary symbolism and its relationship to "Tuesday" the signifier is also arbitrary.  A temporal relationship would be when Tuesday comes before Threesday as it does in Chinese.

Comment: @AaronK by that definition, there can be no such thing as hyponymy, metonymy, synonymy, or indeed any kind of relationship between any two words at all, because all words are arbitrary signifiers. And you completely lost me in that last sentence. I can only parse it such that *Tuesday* comes from *two* and that numbers are related temporally, but you can't seriously be suggesting either, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: They all have the same root [morpheme] (day).

Comment: And @Katherine: the first question is a fair one to ask, but the second one is just weird and nonsensical. It is essentially, "is the relationship car, fingers, astronomy, or yellow?" It's a perplexing mix of terms for which it takes but a lookup of their meaning to immediately see that none of them can possibly apply.

Comment: That part is understandable; what I don't understand is what phenomenon is being addressed. There are no examples, and without data discussion soon decays into terminological quibbling.

Comment: To say, as Edwin does, that the names of the days all have the same morpheme implies that they can be analysed morphologically as "tues + day" etc. But "tues" is not a morpheme in English.

Comment: ...? People do make such strong assertions. If only they'd check their facts first. 'Tues(-)' is at least as much a morpheme as 'cran(-)' in cranberry: _Cranberry morphemes are a special form of bound morphemes where the bound morpheme does not have an independent meaning, only serving to distinguish one word from another, as in cranberry, where the free morpheme berry is preceded by the bound morpheme cran-, which does not have independent meaning._ [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_morpheme). Tues- in Tuesday actually does have meaning (though it too is a bound morpheme): Tew's.

Comment: @RegDwight  I was making a distinction between two types of systems for signifying units of time: one in which opaque symbols are used (such as Mon- Tues- Wednes- ...) that have no stand-alone temporal meaning and another in which the signifiers are numerically transparent (OneDay TwoDay ThreeDay) such as exists in Chinese.  [Further reading](http://mindmodeling.org/cogsci2013/papers/0185/paper0185.pdf)

Comment: Sun's day, Moon's day, Tiwaz's day, Wotan's day, Thor's day, Frig's day, Saturn's day.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the  origin of the names of the week exemplifies their nature:

Although our days of the week are not named directly after the Roman gods, **they are named after the equivalent Anglo-Saxon/Germanic pantheon of gods and display Roman influences**. In fact, English is one of the few Germanic languages to reference the original classical Latin names for days of the week.

Source:http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/08/just-plutonic/

You can find interesting information in the link above. 
Anyway it looks like there us no "lexical" relationship among them but pure symbolism.